# In customer group "Not Logged In" option not saved in db

Tags: magento2

In customer group "Not Logged In" option  alone not saved in db

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $_eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $groupName = 'Hide Price';
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(array('setup' => $setup));


         $eavSetup->addAttribute(
             \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
             'is_hide_price',
             [
                'type' => 'int',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'label' => 'Hide Price Mode',
                'required' => false,
                'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                'default' => '0',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 3,
                'group' => $groupName
             ]
         );

         $eavSetup->addAttribute(
             \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
             'is_customer_group',
             [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'frontend' => '',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'label' => 'Use Current Price Mode By Customer Group',
                'required' => false,
                'source' =>'Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\CustomerGroup',
                'default' => '0',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 4,
                'group' => $groupName
             ]
         );

        $entityTypeId = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getAttributeSetId($entityTypeId, 'Default');

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $groupName, 'is_hide_price');
        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $groupName, 'is_customer_group');

    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Config/Source/CustomerGroup.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection;

class customerGroup extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    protected $_customerGroup;
    protected $_options;

    public function __construct( Collection $customerGroup ) {
    $this->_customerGroup = $customerGroup; 
    }

    public function toOptionArray() 
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
        $this->_options = $this->_customerGroup->toOptionArray();
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
        $this->_options = $this->_customerGroup->toOptionArray();
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

"NOT LOGGED IN" option is selected before saved

[image]

After saved:

[image]

Why **"NOT LOGGED IN"** option value **'0'** not saved in db

1. Product id ----> https://prnt.sc/rbe3wu
2. product attribute id of customer group ---> https://prnt.sc/rbdzuz
3. saved customer group value ---> https://prnt.sc/rbe3hh

Comment: Please add your saved record format.

Comment: I didn't get you @Rohan

Comment: database records save format.

Comment: 1. Product id -->https://prnt.sc/rbe3wu,  2. product attribute id of customer group ---> https://prnt.sc/rbdzuz   3. saved customer group  value ---> https://prnt.sc/rbe3hh

Comment: Just need to change backend_type from text to varchar.

Comment: i already face this issue. i dont why but not getting any type of solution.

Comment: @divyasekar what's your Magento Version? I used same your code. It's working fine so.

Comment: I used Magento 2.1.3 version

Comment: Any Update....?

Comment: no, I just removed a "NOT LOGGED IN" option in the multi-select field.

Comment: @rohan Can you please help me to solve this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309955/checkout-page-error-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Temporary Solution :-**

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $this->_options = [];
        $customerGroup = $this->_customerGroup;
        foreach ($customerGroup as $group){
            if($group->getCustomerGroupId() == 0){
                $group->setCustomerGroupId('999999');
            }
            $this->_options[] = [
                'label' =>$group->getCustomerGroupCode(),
                'value' => $group->getCustomerGroupId()
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;

    }
```

> You Can use **"Not Logged In"** Value As 999999

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps :

1st way :

- Go to your database `eav_attribute`
- Go to `is_customer_group` attribute
- Set `backend_model` NULL

2nd way :

- Go to your database `eav_attribute`
- Go to `is_customer_group` attribute
- Set `backend_type` => `varchar`

**Reindex and clean cache.**

Comment: Nothing happens: https://prnt.sc/rbej6d , db: https://prnt.sc/rbekl2

Comment: No. If you set varchar then backend_model should be Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend

Comment: Set again backend_model value => Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend and backend_type => varchar.
Reindex data and clean cache and again save.

Comment: again it reflects the same  thing  DB - https://prnt.sc/rbepx8,  saving - https://prnt.sc/rber40,  output - https://prnt.sc/rberst

Comment: Did you reindex?

Comment: I did it https://prnt.sc/rbetmu, https://nimb.ws/gQwpSP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105156/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-divya-sekar).